# Trying to find 2 or more occurences in string patterns

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

On execution of my script, I am using 2 input parameters, one for the folder & the other for the string match. Here is my code.

Call file with two arguements // ENSURE OF THIS

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Incorrect use. Try: Sudo $0 FILE PATTERN"
    exit 2
fi
```

Find where the match is and how many times the match occurs.

```
echo ""
echo "Your pattern ${2} occurs in the following files:"
grep  -r -i -l -c $2 $1

echo ""
echo "Pattern match ${2} found this many times:"
grep  -r -o -i $2 $1 | wc -l
```

Print the files in the directory with name & size(bytes)

```
echo ""
echo "Here are the files from the specified parameter search:"
ls -l | awk '{print $9 "\t" $5}'
```

Create an array and store the file names for which occur at least twice in the pattern match.

```
grep $2 $1 -r -c | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -d
```

I can't seem to find only files with 2 occurrences to store in the array, Appreciate all help!!

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: Do you really need to use `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

A few thought on the code snippets -

1. Quote variable usage .. e.g (imagine if $2 is *Fat Cat* it breaks without quoting, or a path */home/User/Path Has Spaces In It/File.txt* )

   ```
   grep  -r -i -l -c $2 $1
   ```

   should be

   ```
   grep  -r -i -l -c "$2" "$1"
   ```
2. Use -c option to grep to count matches.

   > ```
   > -c, --count
   >        Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.
   > ```

   Yes it's similar to `wc -l` but wc puts whitespace everywhere whereas the grep output can be put straight into a variable (if only 1 file is being dealt with - or piped input).
3. If you are trying to search a directory make it clear that's what you are doing (your usage talks about file ...)
4. Give meaningful user output - assume that awk is giving filename and size - but how does the user of the script know?
5. What is the input / expected output you are looking for (final line question not clear).